# Mocking the `open()` system call in C - generating coverage fails

Tags: c, linux, gcov

I've encountered some strange behaviour generating code coverage with `gcov` while mocking out, specifically, the `open()` system call, like this:

```c
// my-coverage.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

const char *open_file_arg = NULL;
int open_oflag_arg = -1;
int open_return_value = -1;

int open(const char *file, int oflag, ...)
{
    open_file_arg = file;
    open_oflag_arg = oflag;
    return open_return_value;
}

int main()
{
    int file = open("./foo", O_RDWR, 0644);
}
```

```bash
$ make CFLAGS=--coverage LDFLAGS=--coverage my-coverage
cc --coverage  --coverage  my-coverage.c   -o my-coverage
$ ./my-coverage 
profiling:/home/deck/playground/my-coverage.gcda:Cannot open
$
```

Other system calls work fine:

```c
// my-coverage.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int pread_fd_arg = -1;
void *pread_buf_arg = NULL;
size_t pread_count_arg = 0;
off_t pread_offset_arg = -1;
ssize_t pread_return_value = -1;

ssize_t pread(int fd, void *buf, size_t count, off_t offset)
{
    pread_fd_arg = fd;
    pread_buf_arg = buf;
    pread_count_arg = count;
    pread_offset_arg = offset;
    return pread_return_value;
}

int main()
{
    ssize_t result = pread(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```bash
$ make CFLAGS=--coverage LDFLAGS=--coverage my-coverage
cc --coverage  --coverage  my-coverage.c   -o my-coverage
$ ./my-coverage 
$ gcov my-coverage.gcda 
File 'my-coverage.c'
Lines executed:100.00% of 7
Creating 'my-coverage.c.gcov'

File '/usr/include/unistd.h'
Lines executed:100.00% of 1
Creating 'unistd.h.gcov'

Lines executed:100.00% of 8
$
```

As do non-system-call functions which use the variable arguments syntax:

```c
// my-coverage.c

int foo(int bar, ...)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return foo(4, 5, 6, 7);
}
```

```bash
$ make CFLAGS=--coverage LDFLAGS=--coverage my-coverage
cc --coverage  --coverage  my-coverage.c   -o my-coverage
$ ./my-coverage 
$ gcov my-coverage.gcda 
File 'my-coverage.c'
Lines executed:100.00% of 4
Creating 'my-coverage.c.gcov'

Lines executed:100.00% of 4
$
```

My question is, why is `gcov` failing to generate code coverage for `open()` specifically? I don't understand what the difference is between `open()` and other system calls I've stubbed, or other library calls I've stubbed. I've not been able to find anything more specific about this issue than, "it affects `open()`".

Comment: It tries to __use__ `open` to actually write the coverage file.

Comment: That's... very obvious, now that you've said it. I don't know why that never occurred to me before...